# IIS, MS SQL and PHP - SQL select in PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql, iis

I have a local MS SQL Database, and a web PHP application on IIS on my server.

On IIS I have successfully connected PHP and my MS SQL database (added connection strings and i see my tables)

But, when I use any SQL select in the PHP web application, it does not work. No data is displayed, or any erros, for example :

```
/* Connect to a MySQL database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=dbname;host=localhost';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';    
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }        
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    $name = $row['id']
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo '$name'?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: try to add error reporting ---- error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Why are you connecting using PDO and then trying to run the deprecated `mysql_query`? Never going to work

Comment: You do realise that MySQL and MS SQL (or SQL Server) are not the same thing right? [mssql_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php)  or just PDO **with the correct connection string** is what you should be using.

Comment: Hello, i have MS SQL Database which i need connect

Answer (score 2):

follow like this for pdo connection

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM users");
$sql->execute();
while($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  ?>
 <tr>
 <td><?php echo $result['name'];?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please follow that code:**

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';

$db   = 'test';

$user = 'root';

$pass = '';

$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";


$opt = 
[

PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,

    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,

    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,

];

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT name FROM users');

while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{

    echo $row['name'] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL (or SqlSrv) and MySql are not working on the sames drivers. You have to know which one you are using and the find PHP functions ables to deal with it.

Note: PHP Extension for using driver must be installed on your server and activated on php.ini file

For MySql do not use mysql_xxx() deprecated functions, prefer mysqli_xxx() to them.

You can find here docs and samples code for both mysql & mssql php functions :

**MySql** :

http://php.net/mysqli_connect

php.net/mysqli_fetch_array

**SqlSrv** :

http://php.net/sqlsrv_connect

php.net/sqlsrv_fetch_array

So what is your database engine ?

Hope that'll helps you, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Mixing the apis would not work - use only PDO methods like this perhaps

```
/* Connect to a MySQL database using driver invocation */
try {
    /* mysql server */
    /* $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=dbname;host=localhost'; */

    /* MS SQL Server */
    $dsn = 'sqlsrv:Database=dbname;Server=localhost';

    $user = 'dbuser';
    $password = 'dbpass';

    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $sql='select * from users';
    $results=$dbh->query( $sql );

    if( $results ){
        while( $rs=$results->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) ){
            echo "<tr><td>{$rs->name}</td></tr>";
        }
    }


} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'sa'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: I now notice ( ? ) that you are using a `MS SQL Database` rather than `mysql`

Comment: Yes MS SQL Database :)

Answer (score 0):

Now working great also with select, with this code :

```
<?php
$serverName = "AC-CLOUD"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Data", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"Masterkey2010");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "SELECT Code, Name FROM StoreCards";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      echo $row['Code'].", ".$row['Name']."<br />";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);


  ?>
```

How now i set this two values into table? this is last point. thank you for your patience and time.